# How can you set office 365 group description to a blank value using the api?

Tags: api, office365, office365api

When attempting to set the description to nothing the following error is returned  Invalid value specified for property 'description' of resource 'Group' for the office 365 groups v1.0 api.

Comment: We can't help you debug without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have set "nothing" to description property like :

```
{
 "description": "",
 "displayName": "Group1",
 "groupTypes":["Unified"],
 "mailEnabled":true,
 "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value1",
 "securityEnabled": false
}
```

That will threw the error you mentioned . If you don't want to set description property , you could remove that in the request body ,or set it to null :

```
{
 "description": null,
 "displayName": "Group1",
 "groupTypes":["Unified"],
 "mailEnabled":true,
 "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value1",
 "securityEnabled": false
}
```